# How to resolve the error: "columns[11]: custom variable cannot be found" when running an SA360 API call?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, double-click-advertising

Heyy!!
Hope everyone is doing well,

I'm pulling data from SA360 (or DS3, Doubleclick Search), although I receive this error when I try to download the report:

> "columns[11]: A custom variable named 'DDA Product Sign Ups' with
> platform source 'FLOODLIGHT' cannot be found.">

I know:

1. That conversion exists on the platform UI (second result)

[image]

2. That my script works because when I take off the conversion field I can deploy my function with no prob.
   My Script (more or less):

```html
conversion_name = "DDA Product Sign Ups"
request = ds3_manager.reports().request(body = 
        {
        "reportScope": {
            "agencyId": agency_id,
            "advertiserId" : advertiser_id },
        "reportType": "adGroup",
        "columns": [
            { "columnName": "date"},
            { "columnName": "accountType"},
            { "columnName": "account" },
            { "columnName": "cost" },
            { "columnName": "impr" },
            { "columnName": "clicks" },
            { 
                "customMetricName" : conversion_name,
                "platformSource": "floodlight"
            }
        ],
        "timeRange": {
        "startDate": start_date,
        "endDate": end_date
        },
        "downloadFormat": "csv",
        "maxRowsPerFile": 6000000,
        "statisticsCurrency": "agency"
        }
        )
```

When I google the issue I land on this web result: [Set up custom Floodlight metrics and dimensions](https://support.google.com/searchads/answer/6024747)  but I don't understand, to me, it is already set up, as I can add to it to my reports on the UI or on my webqueries already... So I'm not why it is not picked up by the script..

If anyone has an idea that would be greatly appreciated :D.
Best,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

In order to include custom columns in a report request, you first need to find out how that custom column is defined (check this [link](https://developers.google.com/search-ads/v2/how-tos/reporting/saved-columns#get-a-list-of-saved-columns)). You can then include the custom column in the request (check this [link](https://developers.google.com/search-ads/v2/how-tos/reporting/saved-columns#request-reports-for-saved-columns)).

You will find useful information on this topic in the *"Optional: Request for Specific User-defined Column"* section of this [article](https://www.pingshiuanchua.com/blog/post/pulling-data-from-doubleclick-search-directly-into-python).